# Building GEOS / GDAL halts on embedding manifest files

Tags: gdal, visual-studio, geos

I'm trying to build GEOS and GDAL from source on a Windows machine.  I have **Visual C++ for Python 9.0** installed with Lib / Include / PATH environment variables established (as far as I am aware). But I encounter a fatal error when trying to build GEOS and GDAL from source. I am using the following call to build **GEOS** in the GEOS root folder:

```
nmake /f makefile.vc MSVC_VER=1500
```

It compiles fine then exits on:

```
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 9.00.30729.01

Creating library geos_i.lib and object geos_i.exp
if exist geos.dll.manifest mt -manifest geos.dll.manifest -outputresource:geos.dll;2
NMAKE: fatal error U1077: 'if' return code '0xc000005'
```

After this error occurs, the source folder contains **geos.dll** as well as **geos.dll.manifest**. And, if I were to run the command `nmake /f makefile.vc MSVC_VER=1500` again, it would pass on this instance but fail on a future one with the same error. By continuing to execute the nmake command I can eventually get through building geos.

I seem to recall that trying to compile each step by hand I got a more descriptive error message from `mt` saying that geos.dll could not be found. But when navigating to the folder, it is clearly there. And running the `mt` command by hand works just fine.

Any thoughts? I'm pretty new to building / compiling on Windows.

Comment: I know Visual Studio is supposed to be more flexible with paths, but it wouldn't hurt to make sure your build path is sane (no spaces/special characters in folder names). Large build systems can break down pretty quickly due to one path reference not being escaped properly...Also, this question may be better off at [so].

Comment: Questions about compiling software, even GIS software, are really software development questions, more suited to Stack Overflow, since there is no clear GIS component.

Comment: @Vince Thanks for the suggestion. That's where I originally had it posted but it was pretty stale over there. I'm more than happy to put it back up over there. If so, should I delete this post or let it sit?

Comment: @EvilGenius Thanks for the suggestion. I'll take a look and make sure that everything is as error proof as possible.